# Deprecated Gradle features, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0

Tags: android, linux, react-native, gradle

I am getting the error that **Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.** But I'm using **gradle 6.5.1.**
Can anyone help me out.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe6EY.png) is the image

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning check out for another errors you might get.

For me I got Gradle error and deleting the .gradle folder worked for me.

Also you can try

npm install --save-dev jetifier
npx jetify
npx react-native run-android

for successful run or try open your android folder with Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

They are just warnings telling you you'll hit problems if/when you upgrade to Gradle 7.0, so its up to you what you do about them now:

1. ignore them - yeah they add bloat to the build logs, but are you bothered about that?
2. hide them - ah, you are bothered about them being in the logs, then hide them by using --warning-mode=none.
3. resolve them - make you project ready for Gradle 7.0 (even if not planning to upgrade anytime soon) by sorting out the warnings now, use --warning-mode=fail to help you find and fix them all.

See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings for the available options, consider adding org.gradle.warning.mode=fail  into you project's gradle.properties to ensure developers don't add more deprecated usages.